# Nokogiri find css fails when node has xmlns attribute

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, xpath, nokogiri, xml-namespaces

Simple query:

```
Nokogiri::XML('<a xmlns=""></a>').css("a")
```

returns:

```
Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError: // :a
from nokogiri/XmlXpathContext.java:123:in `evaluate'
```

but:

```
Nokogiri::XML('<a xmlns=""></a>').xpath("a")
```

returns:

```
[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3864 name="a">]
```

Is it bug in Nokogiri gem? Or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: I am using jruby 1.7.10 and nokogiri 1.6.1

Comment: What version of Nokogiri are you using? Try `nokogiri -v` at the command-line. v1.6.1 is current.

Comment: `pry(main)> Nokogiri::VERSION
=> "1.6.1"` ... did you try it? And does the css query work for you?

Answer (score 1):

The jruby nokogiri is quite different from the C version, they use different engines.  Unfortunately the namespace issue is well known and there are a few different issues in github issues:

here's the big one.
https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/902

I've had the same issue and have not been able to find a good work around.  I'm trying to parse html, so for my jruby version, I'm just wrapping jsoup (a java library)